# CSS: content not displaying

Tags: css

On [this site](http://test.doig.com.au/MHM/), if I inspect "What We Do", I see the HTML code:

```
<a title="What we do – Mad Hat Media" href="http://test.doig.com.au/MHM/services/" class="sf-with-ul">What We Do<span class="sf-sub-indicator"> »</span></a>
```

with CSS code:

```
.menu li a .sf-sub-indicator, .menu li li a .sf-sub-indicator, .menu li li li a .sf-sub-indicator {
    background: none;
    content: '&raquo;';
    color: #622C82;
}
```

**I can't see why the** `content: '&raquo;'` **does not display**. The CSS element has a width and a colour.

What is missing are the drop down indicators (indicated by the green arrows in the screen shot below)

[image]

Help appreciated.

Comment: Make sure that you are using the UTF-8 character set.

Comment: `content` is an attribute for pseudoelements `::after` and `::before`, not for plain css selectors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you should have a look at this class

```
.menu li a .sf-sub-indicator,
.menu li li a .sf-sub-indicator,
.menu li li li a .sf-sub-indicator {
    background: url(images/arrow-down.png) no-repeat;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 5px;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    top: 13px;
    width: 16px;
}
```

the **text-indent** property causes the >> to go AWOL. Remove that and you are *kinda* set. You may have to toggle other classes though.

As for the drop down indicators, they are very much present, just remove the `background:none`

On that note, `content` property is usually set to `::before` and `::after` pseudoelement. Do have a look into [this mdn link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/content) .

Comment: Thanks. I ended up replacing the default dropdown arrow that had been hidden with `.menu li a .sf-sub-indicator, .menu li li a .sf-sub-indicator, .menu li li li a .sf-sub-indicator {
    background: url(images/arrow-right2.png) no-repeat;
}`

Answer (score 1):

As I can see in your code selectors `.menu li a .sf-sub-indicator`, `.menu li li a .sf-sub-indicator`, `.menu li li li a .sf-sub-indicator` look almost equal.

Anyway if you want implement `content` attribute it's better to write something like:

```
.sf-sub-indicator::after {
    background: none;
    content: '&raquo;';
    color: #622C82;
}
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L55HS.jpg

Comment: Thanks Banzay. I've made that change, and the content appears in the HTML, but it [does not display visually](http://test.doig.com.au/MHM/).

Comment: this works: `.menu li a .sf-sub-indicator::after, .menu li li a .sf-sub-indicator, .menu li li li a .sf-sub-indicator {
    background: none;
    content: '&raquo;';
    color: #622C82;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Background image is set for this span.
Inspect it again:

```
.menu li a .sf-sub-indicator, .menu li li a .sf-sub-indicator, .menu li li li a .sf-sub-indicator {
background: url(images/arrow-right2.png) no-repeat;
}
```